# Method in C# counting doesn't count

Tags: c#

I have this Method:

```
public int IndexOf(string text)
        {

            for (Node i = Head; i != null; i = i.Next)
            {
                int counter = 0;
                if (text == i.Text)
                {
                    return counter;
                }

                counter++;
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

Now I have 4 strings in my list, and the Index is always 0. I can't find out where the problem is.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are initializing `counter = 0` in for loop, initialize counter variable outside of it.

In your case, Counter variable is initialized to 0 inside for loop, for each iteration counter variable becoming zero and at the end of loop it is incrementing by one.

If you print value of `counter` while initialization and increment, you will understand what modification you want in your code.

```
public int IndexOf(string text)
        {

            for (Node i = Head; i != null; i = i.Next)
            {
                int counter = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("Value of counter = "+ counter);
                if (text == i.Text)
                {
                    return counter;
                }

                counter++;
                Console.WriteLine("Value of counter post increment = "+ counter);
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

I pointed out where are you going wrong. Other answers will show you what changes you need to do in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `counter` variable out of loop,

```
    public int IndexOf(string text)
    {
        int counter = -1;
        for (Node i = Head; i != null; i = i.Next)
        {
            counter++;
            if (text == i.Text)
            {
                return counter;
            }                
        }
        return -1;
    }
```